# Maven build fails with - Process exited with an error: 126

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

I'm running maven build with command -

```
mvn clean install -DdestFolder=<destination-folder-path>
```

but it fails with following error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (Transpilation) on project UI: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 126 (Exit value: 126) -> [Help 1]
```

I'm unable to get cause of 126 error code. Could you please help to understand the cause?